# Spring-amqp with empty queue name is awaiting_declaration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I want to create a queue with empty name so that the name can be generated by RabbitMQ -

```
var queue = QueueBuilder
    .durable("")
    .exclusive()
    .autoDelete().build

var binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(bindingKey).noargs();
Declarables d = new Declarables(queue, binding);
```

But then calling getActualName returns: *spring.gen-vuiRwjOmRkihAE8C72rbmw_awaiting_declaration*

```
d.getDeclarablesByType(Queue.class).get(0).getActualName();
```

while in rabbitMQ the name is: *amq.gen-wpaYnybu9vOdD5v2ej66IQ*

In spring-amqp core the Queue constructor declares:

```
    public Queue(String name, boolean durable, boolean exclusive, boolean autoDelete,
            @Nullable Map<String, Object> arguments) {
    
        super(arguments);
        Assert.notNull(name, "'name' cannot be null");
        this.name = name;
        this.actualName = StringUtils.hasText(name) ? name
                : (Base64UrlNamingStrategy.DEFAULT.generateName() 
+ "_awaiting_declaration");
        this.durable = durable;
        this.exclusive = exclusive;
        this.autoDelete = autoDelete;
    }
```

Why is spring Queue using Base64UrlNamingStrategy and adding "awaiting_declaration" when we want the rabbitMQ name? How can we get the rabbitMQ name and not the spring generated name?

Queue defintion: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/d4e0f5c366a7ffae073f608c3766c82064cab3d1/spring-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/core/Queue.java#L98

Reason for this use-case is because of race-condition on queues:
"When auto-delete or exclusive queues use well-known (static) names, in case of client disconnection and immediate reconnection there will be a natural race condition between RabbitMQ nodes that will delete such queues and recovering clients that will try to re-declare them. This can result in client-side connection recovery failure or exceptions, and create unnecessary confusion or affect application availability."

https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#properties

Spring suggests using broker-based queues which can result in race condition:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#containers-and-broker-named-queues

EDIT:
We are are not initiating the connection ourselves, but the admin bean initiates it after d.setAdminsThatShouldDelcare(admin)

```
    public Declarables someEventsDeclarables(
    @Qualifier("rabbitAdmin") RabbitAdmin admin,
    @Qualifier("AmqpExchange") Exchange exchange
) {
    final var bindingKey = somePrefix +".*." +someSuffix
    final var cfg = new OurEventsDeclarables(
        exchange,
        "", // no queue name - RabbitMq generates it
        bindingKey,
        true
    );

    final var declarables = cfg.declarables();
    for (Declarable d : declarables.getDeclarables()) {
        d.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin);
        admin.declareQueue();
    }
    return declarables;
}
```

Running the integration-test which uses the queue results in

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[spring.gen-QUh8ffN0TimELGG_kF1wFw_awaiting_declaration]
```

Edit-2 - working solution (in other tests Declarables and AutoAckConsumer might need to be @MockBean):

```
public class AmqpConfig{
...
@Bean("someEventsDeclarables")
public Declarables someEventsDeclarables(
@Qualifier("rabbitAdmin") RabbitAdmin admin,
@Qualifier("AmqpExchange") Exchange exchange
) {
final var bindingKey = somePrefix +".*." +someSuffix
final var cfg = new OurEventsDeclarables(
    exchange,
    "", // no queue name - RabbitMq generates it
    bindingKey,
    true
);

final var declarables = cfg.declarables();

/** declare queue and bindings */
final List<Queue> queues = declarables.getDeclarablesByType(Queue.class);
final List<Binding> bindings = declarables.getDeclarablesByType(Binding.class);
if (queues.size() == 0) {
    throw new BeanCreationException("Queue for empty-queue-name is not found");
}
if (bindings.size() == 0) {
    throw new BeanCreationException("Binding for {} is not found of empty-queue-name", bindingKey);
}
Queue queue = queues.get(0);
Binding binding = bindings.get(0);
String declareQueue = admin.declareQueue(queue);
queue.setActualName(declareQueue);
admin.declareBinding(binding);
return declarables;
}
```

Comment: How are you declaring the queue? When declaring via `RabbitAdmin`, the actual name is populated from the `DeclareOk` result: `queue.setActualName(declareOk.getQueue());`.

Comment: Ive edit the question with a code-snippet from our code that calls d.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin); which should make the admin bean initiate the connection.

Comment: You are using the wrong method - see my answer.

Comment: I dont have access to the queue - just Declarables which was created using `return new Declarables(queue, binding);`

Comment: `getDeclarablesByType(Queue.class)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `admin.declareQueue()` (and discarding its result) instead of `admin.declareQueue(Queue queue)`.

The first method just declares a broker named queue; the update to the actual name requires the `Queue` object (so it can update the name).

Comment: How do I get a hold of the queue? In the declarable i have a queue because cfg.declarables(); does: 
`var queue = QueueBuilder.durable(queueName).exclusive().autoDelete().build();
var binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(bindingKey).noargs();
return new Declarables(queue, binding);`

Comment: `Declarables` is not really intended for this use case, it is intended for auto declaration of `@Bean`s found in the application context, by the admin. That said, you can use `declarables.getDeclarablesByType()` to get a list of `Queue` objects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I need to `admin.declareQueue(Queue queue)` and keep the returned queue name to call `queue.setAcutalName(returnedQueueName)`. I also needed to declare the binding. Updated question with working solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what and where you do with that `Queue` object.
You must have a `RabbitAdmin` bean in the application context. As well as all those `Declarable` instances has to be declared as beans as well. Then when application context starts, that `RabbitAdmin` takes all the `Declarable` beans and declares them against the broker. The further logic around `Queue` is like this:

```
DeclareOk declareOk = channel.queueDeclare(queue.getName(), queue.isDurable(),
                            queue.isExclusive(), queue.isAutoDelete(), queue.getArguments());
if (StringUtils.hasText(declareOk.getQueue())) {
    queue.setActualName(declareOk.getQueue());
}
```

Just creating variables for those types does not initiate any connection to the broker to perform objects creation and bindings between them.

Comment: Ive edit the question with a code-snippet from our code that calls d.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(admin); which should make the admin bean initiate the connection.